# Error: No se encontró la extensión mysqli. Revisa la configuración PHP. Revise nuestra documentación para más información

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin

tengo el error "No se encontró la extensión mysqli. Revisa la configuración PHP. Revise nuestra documentación para más información."
estoy instalando el phpmyadmin en el servidor
actualmente mi servidor es debian 10 buster con php -v = 8.1.9
agradeceria como solucionar el detalle.

Comment: `sudo apt install php-mysql` o dependiendo de la version: `php8.1-mysql`

Comment: hola, intente con el comando : sudo apt install php8.1-mysql y me dio:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php8.1-mysql is already the newest version (8.1.9-1+0~20220815.24+debian10~1.gbp4d5b5a).
php8.1-mysql set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

Comment: Usa un `phpinfo()` y en el resultado revisa la sección `mysqli`. Después de instalar `php8.1-mysql` tienes que reiniciar el servidor web.